# DELETE statement issues within a trigger definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I have created an insert/update trigger that is designed to update information in a different table based on the data being inserted. The last thing the trigger does (or is supposed to do) is remove all data from a target table with conditions that may have changed during the insert portions of the trigger.

Everything appears to be working with the trigger except the final `DELETE` statement. It is executing the `DELETE` statement, but not following any of the conditions in the where clause. It simply deletes everything in the table.

I have even tried changing the `NOT IN` in the where clause to `IN`, and it still does the same. I have isolated the `DELETE` statement and tested outside the trigger and it works fine (using the same variables and subqueries).

Am I missing something with the behavior of a trigger?

Here comes the code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[cust_trgr_profile_attribute] 
ON [dbo].[port_module_instance_setting]      
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @ModuleId INT=449,
        @MatchGroupModSetting VARCHAR(50) = 'AttributeGroup',
        @FilterGroupModSetting VARCHAR(50) = 'FilterAttributeGroup',
        @MatchAttributes TABLE (attribute_id INT),
        @FilterAttributes TABLE (attribute_id INT)

INSERT INTO @MatchAttributes
  SELECT DISTINCT camatch.attribute_id 
  FROM inserted I
  JOIN core_attribute camatch ON I.value = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), camatch.attribute_group_id)
  JOIN port_module_instance pmi ON I.module_instance_id = pmi.module_instance_id
       AND pmi.module_id=@ModuleId
  WHERE I.name like @MatchGroupModSetting+'_'

INSERT INTO @FilterAttributes
  SELECT DISTINCT cafilter.attribute_id 
  FROM inserted I
  JOIN core_attribute cafilter ON I.value = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cafilter.attribute_group_id)
  JOIN port_module_instance pmi ON I.module_instance_id = pmi.module_instance_id
       AND pmi.module_id=@ModuleId
  WHERE I.name=@FilterGroupModSetting

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MatchAttributes) > 0 OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FilterAttributes) > 0)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MatchAttributes) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE cpa 
           SET cpa.[required]=0
          FROM cust_profile_attribute cpa
          JOIN @MatchAttributes ma ON cpa.attribute_id = ma.attribute_id
    END

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FilterAttributes) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE cpa 
           SET cpa.[required]=0
          FROM cust_profile_attribute cpa
          JOIN @FilterAttributes fa ON cpa.attribute_id=fa.attribute_id
    END

    DELETE FROM cust_profile_attribute
    WHERE attribute_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct ca.attribute_id 
                               FROM core_attribute ca
                               JOIN port_module_instance_setting inst ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ca.attribute_group_id) = inst.value
                               JOIN port_module_instance modinst ON inst.module_instance_id = modinst.module_instance_id
                                    AND modinst.module_id = @ModuleId
                               WHERE inst.name like @MatchGroupModSetting + '_'
                               OR inst.name like @FilterGroupModSetting)
END
```

Comment: One can guess from the Microsoft-style `@`, but why would you force people to guess your RDBMS, when you can just tell?

Comment: Erwin, I apologize for my ignorance, but I am not quite sure what you mean. Are you saying I need to say something about this being an MSSQL setup?

Comment: Can attribute_id be NULL? Much better to use NOT EXISTS or a LEFT OUTER JOIN than NOT IN.

Comment: Try qualifying the `distinct attribute_id` in the final `SELECT` with the appropriate alias on the column.  It just looks ambiguous.

Comment: I am saying you have to name the RDBMS you are working with for a question like that. Goes without saying. Don't make people guess, that is just disrespecting the time of those trying to help. a_horse_with_no_name did the job for you in the meantime.

Comment: @Aaron-No, attribute_id cannot be null. Thanks for your tip on tidying up a little, but the NOT IN doesn't seem to be where the problem is.

Comment: @Edwin, I still have no clue what you are talking about. If you are referring to the (MSSQL) added to the question, I added that after your comment. If that is not what you meant, then I am still not following your concern. Sorry.

Comment: @HABO- the entire delete statement is actually independent of the inserted/updated data. It is a "clean-up" transaction to go remove data that has potentially been rendered "junk" by the changes made that invoked the trigger. I may try to break the delete out into it's own trigger.

Comment: Erwin Brandstetter probably meant to suggest you adding an appropriate *tag* to your question, which has been added now (`sql-server`). And we tend not to put product names into question titles since we usually have corresponding tags for that. (Removed `(MSSQL)` from the title.)

Comment: @Andriy- Thanks for the clarification! I am all for forum etiquette. I am just not fully up to speed on this one :)

Comment: @gmaness: Why do you say that the NOT IN is not where the problem is?  It seems extremely likely that that is where it must be.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Because the column it is pulling from does not allow NULLs, and because I can run the full delete statement outside the context of the trigger, and it works properly (only deleting things I want it to.

Comment: Then how do you know that it is this DELETE statement in the trigger that is doing it?  You need to run the Profiler and find out for sure what is really going on here.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: 2 reasons.. 1) I can comment out the DELETE statement, and all the other parts of the trigger are functioning fine. 2) The DELETE statement in the trigger is the only piece of code anywhere in the process that is issuing a DELETE to that table.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a flaw in my fundamental logic of how the trigger works. I have now refined my understanding of what is going on and able to articulate more information for others to help. Rather than try to completely transform the original post, I thought it better to post the new info here.

The basic idea is that the `port_module_instance_setting` table stores a string in the  that represents a setting (in this specific case, the conditions are set so that the `value` field will always be a number). What I am trying to accomplish is that when the `value` field is updated in one of these specific "settings", everything in the  `cust_profile_attribute` table that is referenced by the old `value` gets deleted. In this context, the `value` field of `port_module_instance_setting` is a numeric varchar value that directly references the `attribute_group_id` of `core_attribute`. Please don't comment on best practices regarding referencing tables using different data types, as I have no control over the actual table structure :) 
Everything in the trigger functions properly, except the `DELETE` statement at the end. It isn't doing anything. Any ideas on why it isn't deleting the attributes I want it to?

I have changed the `DELETE` statement as follows to reference the pre-updated `value`field.

```
DELETE FROM cust_profile_attribute
WHERE attribute_id IN(SELECT ISNULL(attribute_id,-1) FROM deleted d
                      JOIN core_attribute ca ON ca.attribute_group_id= CONVERT(INT,d.value))
```