# Can't get DELETE statement to work within my SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

I have created the trigger below. The basic idea is that the `port_module_instance_setting` table stores a string in the  that represents a setting (in this specific case, the conditions are set so that the `value` field will always be a number). What I am trying to accomplish is that when the `value` field is updated in one of these specific "settings", everything in the  `cust_profile_attribute` table that is referenced by the old `value` gets deleted. In this context, the `value` field of `port_module_instance_setting` is a numeric varchar value that directly references the `attribute_group_id` of `core_attribute`. Please don't comment on best practices regarding referencing tables using different data types, as I have no control over the actual table structure :) 
Everything in the trigger functions properly, except the `DELETE` statement at the end. It isn't doing anything. Any ideas on why it isn't deleting the attributes I want it to?

CODE:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[cust_trgr_profile_attribute] 
ON [dbo].[port_module_instance_setting]      
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @ModuleId INT=449,
        @MatchGroupModSetting VARCHAR(50) = 'AttributeGroup',
        @FilterGroupModSetting VARCHAR(50) = 'FilterAttributeGroup',
        @MatchAttributes TABLE (attribute_id INT),
        @FilterAttributes TABLE (attribute_id INT)

INSERT INTO @MatchAttributes
  SELECT DISTINCT camatch.attribute_id 
  FROM inserted I
  JOIN core_attribute camatch ON I.value = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), camatch.attribute_group_id)
  JOIN port_module_instance pmi ON I.module_instance_id = pmi.module_instance_id
       AND pmi.module_id=@ModuleId
  WHERE I.name like @MatchGroupModSetting+'_'

INSERT INTO @FilterAttributes
  SELECT DISTINCT cafilter.attribute_id 
  FROM inserted I
  JOIN core_attribute cafilter ON I.value = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cafilter.attribute_group_id)
  JOIN port_module_instance pmi ON I.module_instance_id = pmi.module_instance_id
       AND pmi.module_id=@ModuleId
  WHERE I.name=@FilterGroupModSetting

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MatchAttributes) > 0 OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FilterAttributes) > 0)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MatchAttributes) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE cpa 
           SET cpa.[required]=0
          FROM cust_profile_attribute cpa
          JOIN @MatchAttributes ma ON cpa.attribute_id = ma.attribute_id
    END

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FilterAttributes) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE cpa 
           SET cpa.[required]=0
          FROM cust_profile_attribute cpa
          JOIN @FilterAttributes fa ON cpa.attribute_id=fa.attribute_id
    END
    DELETE FROM cust_profile_attribute
    WHERE attribute_id IN(SELECT ISNULL(attribute_id,-1) FROM deleted d
                          JOIN core_attribute ca ON ca.attribute_group_id= CONVERT(INT,d.value))
    END
```

Comment: Duplicated, same question asked 17h ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767725/delete-statement-issues-within-a-trigger-definition

Comment: @Yaroslav: You are close to correct (and super fast). I did originally ask this at the link you provided, but have had significant findings that would have been a nightmare to try to edit/explain in the original question. I decided (not saying it is the best decision) to repost the question as I now understand it, then answer the original with a link to this one. That was a pretty quick judgement to dock me a point without even giving me a chance to explain.

Comment: Well, I don't know what other (not to say older) users agree with. But I think that as your previous question had so many comments you could edit it and add the new findings. This way anyone can use the comments and add their own new answers/comments. And it was superfast as you say because on your first question I was trying to unravel the code and see what was wrong and sticked to my head.

Comment: @Yaroslav: As far as the code goes, the only thing that changed is now the DELETE statement is referencing the actual deleted data info from the UPDATE triggering event. I have also added some info in the question to hopefully aid in how the data is related to help unravel this stuff.
As far as forum practices, what would you recommend? I thought that the forum frowns on long strings of comments, so I got worried. Should I go back and completely make-over the original question with a massive edit?

Answer (score 0):

Added relevant information to the original question (
[DELETE statement issues within a trigger definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767725/delete-statement-issues-within-a-trigger-definition)) Taking this as lesson learned (and my -1 point) and answering the post to hopefully kill it. Please click the link to see the original quesiton.

Comment: There you have, a +1 on the other question for detailing ;)